# If $Y_t$ is not white noise, why $X_t$ can't be Normal?

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, arima, white-noise

> Let $\{X_t\}$ be an white noise process and $\{Y_t\}$ a second process
>   where $Y_t=X_t^2$. If $Y_t$ is not white noise, why you can say that
>   $X_t$ don't have Normal distribution?

I can not see the connection between normality and white noise in this case. By definition:

If $X_t$ is an white noise process then $E(X_t)=0$ (assuming it), $Var(X_t)<\infty$ and $Cov(X_t,X_s)=0$ for $t\neq s$.

If $X_t$ were Normal then $Y_t$ would have chi-square distribution, but why $X_t$ can't be Normal if $X_t^2$ is not white noise?

Comment: Can you point to the source of the question?

Comment: @broncoAbierto It's from a list of exercises about ARIMA models that I get from web, but the page is not online anymore.

Comment: How can Yt be white noise when all Yt >= 0

Comment: @jf328 But why $X_t$ can't be Normal?

Comment: @Roland, I mean the question is not correctly stated. Whatever Xt is, Yt is not white noise. Xt may well be Normal

Comment: @jf328 Understood, it should probably be a mistake in the question then.